# Check if an input is equal to any item in the list

Tags: python

let's say we have a list

```
a=["a1", "a2", "a3"]
```

then we have an input:

```
x=input("enter something: ")
```

how would you check if that input "x" is equal to any item in the list and then return true?

Comment: You can do `if x in a: return True`.

Comment: it is not a duplicate of that article as i have a different situation

Comment: How is it different? Can you be more specific?

Comment: I didn't really want to disclose this information but I'm trying to make a naughts and crosses game and I've created lists to hold the data of each square in the naughts and crosses. I will then ask for an input and use that input, not to count how many times it repeats but use it to simply see whether the input correlates to a keyword to describe each square. I just did not find my answer on that particular post

Comment: @slider Just `x in a` will do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check it with that code:

```
print("Yes, x in list" if x in a else "No, x is not in list")
```

It same that:

```
if x in a:
    print("Yes, x in list")
else:
    print("No, x is not in list")
```

Also if you want to get index of contained element - just use `.index()`:

```
if x in a: 
    print('Yes, x in list, and it index is:', a.index(x))
```

In that example i'am avoid `else:` construct, but you can use it like in previous example, if you need it.